# Javascript pattern test on client input

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects, regexp-replace

I'm creating an Input element on client side and gave a pattern to an input in HTML,

it should prevent user inputs according to the given pattern,

it doesn't work as I stated in the code below,

it returns true every time, it doesn't test the regex pattern properly

```
init(params) {
        // ^(\d{1,9}\.\d{1,3})|(\.\d{1,3})|(\d{1,9})$
        // create the cell
        // <input class="" pattern="asdasd"/>
        debugger;
        this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
        this.eInput.className = 'ag-input-field-input ag-text-field-input';
        //var regex = /^(\d{1,9}\.\d{1,3})|(\.\d{1,3})|(\d{1,9})$/;
        this.eInput.setAttribute("pattern", "^(\\d{1,9}\\.\\d{1,3})|(\\.\\d{1,3})|(\\d{1,9})$");
        /* var a = regex.test(params.value);*/
        if (this.isCharNumeric(params.charPress)) {
            this.eInput.value = params.charPress;
        } else {
            if (params.value !== undefined && params.value !== null) {
                this.eInput.value = params.value;
            }
        }

        this.eInput.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
            var regex = new RegExp(/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(\.\d{1,3})|(\d{1,3})/);

            if (!this.isKeyPressedNumeric(event)) {
                this.eInput.focus();
                if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
            } else if (this.isKeyPressedNavigation(event)) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (event.target.value != "") {
                if (!regex.test(event.key)) {
                    console.log('FALSE INPUT');
                    this.eInput.focus();
                    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    console.log('VALID INPUT');
                }
            }
            
        });

        // only start edit if key pressed is a number, not a letter
        var charPressIsNotANumber =
            params.charPress && '1234567890'.indexOf(params.charPress) < 0;
        this.cancelBeforeStart = !!charPressIsNotANumber;
    }
```

I've tested other regex patterns that works normally, but none of them works in my case

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the issue. There should be no calls to functions that are irrelevant to the problem. Make sure that what remains is still runnable and produces the issue. As it is now, there is no event triggered, because the input element is not part of the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test input against a regex as it is being input, then you need to use a second regex that accepts any legal prefix of all the valid strings. Then when the input loses focus (`onblur` event), you test the input against the original regex to make sure it is a full match. I would use the `keyup` even on which it is possible that the text has changed in the input widget. Then you test your regex against the current value. If it is a valid prefix, then you could save it somewhere and if it is not a valid prefix, then you would restore the previously saved value.

The following should give you the basic idea. If I have misunderstood your question, please let me know and I will delete this answer.

```js
function setup(inputWidget, msgWidget, fullRegex, prefixRegex)
{
      inputWidget.focus();
      inputWidget.value = '';
      let save_text = inputWidget.value;

      inputWidget.addEventListener('blur', (/* event */) => {
          if (!fullRegex.test(inputWidget.value)) {
              msgWidget.innerHTML = 'Invalid input.';
          }
          else {
            console.log('Valid text.');
          }
      });

      inputWidget.addEventListener('keyup', (/* event */) => {
          if (!prefixRegex.test(inputWidget.value)) {
              inputWidget.value = save_text;
              msgWidget.innerHTML = 'Invalid input.';
          }
          else {
              save_text = inputWidget.value;
              msgWidget.innerHTML = '';
          }
      });
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', (/* event */) => {
      setup(document.getElementById('text'),
            document.getElementById('msg'),
            /^(\d{1,9}\.\d{1,3})|(\.\d{1,3})|(\d{1,9})$/,
            /^(\d{0,9}|\d{1,9}\.|\d{1,9}\.\d{1,3})$/
           );
  });
```

```html
<input  type="text" id="text" size="20"> <span id='msg' style="color: red;"></span>
```